# Localized XML documentation files for .NET Framework

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, localization, xml-documentation

If you install a localized version of Visual Studio, you'll get localized XML documentation files in the Reference Assemblies folder, like

```
C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETFramework\v4.0\de
```

But these files are only installed if you install a localized version of Visual Studio. I wonder if there is a way to get these localization files without (re)installing Visual Studio? There are, however, [language packs](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=21615) for VS which also install localized XML documentation files, but I haven't found language packs for the main languages that are built in localized VS editions. And Windows SDK installs only in English.

So here is my question: is there any way to get (or redistribute) localized XML files for .NET Framework?

Answer (score 0):

Just a partial answer from my experience: In the help system, Win32 (the Windows SDK) is only available in English, while most other (.NET) content is available in English and my local language. I guess that you won't get any localised Windows SDK documentation because it doesn't exist.

No idea about your other questions though. Maybe you could copy them from another installation of a localised Visual Studio build? I guess if Microsoft doesn't offer them somewhere, nobody else would be allowed to redistribute them.